# Custom Observer include (): failed

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, extensions, xml

I've created an extension following a few tutorials which is meant to create an observer in order to add a layout handle.

in my logs I get the following on each page load

```
2017-01-25T14:56:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Karl\CustomHandles.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94
2017-01-25T14:56:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Karl\CustomHandless.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\app\code\local;C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\app\code\community;C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\app\code\core;C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\lib;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')  in C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94
2017-01-25T14:56:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Karl\CustomHandles.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94
2017-01-25T14:56:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Karl\CustomHandless.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\app\code\local;C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\app\code\community;C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\app\code\core;C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\lib;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')  in C:\xampp\htdocs\raanthai2\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94
```

The path to the file seems to be affected by the class tag, in `Karl\CustomHandles\etc\config.xml` which is

```
<config>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <observers>
                <customhandles>
                    <class>Karl_CustomHandles</class>
                    <method>addCustomHandles</method>
                </customhandles>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_load_before>
    </events>

    <layout>
        <updates>
            <karl_customhandles module="Karl_CustomHandles">
                <file>customhandles.xml</file>
            </karl_customhandles>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Karl_CustomHandles` is the name of the module and there should be no class called like that. If this is really the class name of your observer, first change it to `Karl_CustomHandles_Model_Observer` (it should be in the file `Karl\CustomHandles\Model\Observer.php` so that Magento can find it)

Then change the line in your config.xml to

```
                <class>Karl_CustomHandles_Model_Observer</class>
```

---

Or, even better, use a model alias:

```
<config>

    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <customhandles>
                        <class>customhandles/observer</class>
                        <method>addCustomHandles</method>
                    </customhandles>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <models>
            <customhandles>
                <class>Karl_CustomHandles_Model</class>
            </customhandles>
        </models>
    </global>

</config>
```

This is the recommended practice because other modules are now able to rewrite your observer model. But if this is just a custom module in your own project, the first solution with the class name should be good enough.

Comment: Does this mean it's necessary for the observers class name to match the path?

This worked perfectly by the way.

Comment: yes, **all** class names in Magento must match the file path. The only special case are controllers, where the `controllers` directory is not part of the class name.